# How to give folder permission with separe folder and files?

Tags: permissions

I want to do this on my current var/www/html folder flowing permissions. how to do that?

Set the following permissions.

a. `sudo chgrp -R www-data`
b. `sudo chmod -R ug+rwx`

To the following folders.

c. `./bootstrap`
d. `./storage`
e. `./public`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) allows for very compact commands.

`echo /var/www/html/{bootstrap,storage,public}`

Outputs

`/var/www/html/bootstrap /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/public`

Your commands could be expressed as.

`sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html/{bootstrap,storage,public}`
`sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/html/{bootstrap,storage,public}`